# Unusual error: expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’/expected initializer before ‘delete’

Tags: c, avl-tree

I'm trying to adapt this code about AVL Trees But I get compile errors

These are the errors obtained:

```
gerasg@gerasg-iMac:~/Escritorio/AVLTREE$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic main.c avltree.c -o avl.exe
In file included from main.c:3:0:
avltree.h:24:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’
avltree.h:24:7: error: expected initializer before ‘delete’
In file included from avltree.c:3:0:
avltree.h:24:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’
avltree.h:24:7: error: expected initializer before ‘delete’
avltree.c:205:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’
avltree.c:205:7: error: expected initializer before ‘delete’
```

Before you ask me, my teacher requires us to use the g++ compiler, and write the code in C.
I know that sounds weird, but it's his desire.

And here is the code with which I have been fighting:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "avltree.h"

int main()
{
    node *t;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    const int max = 10;

    printf("--- C AVL Tree Demo  ---\n");

    t = NULL;

    printf("Insert: ");
    for( i = 0; i < max; i++, j = ( j + 7 ) % max )
    {

        t = insert( j, t );
        printf("%d ",j);

    }
    printf(" into the tree\n\n");

    display_avl(t);

    dispose(t);

    return 0;
}
```

avltree.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "avltree.h"
/*
    remove all nodes of an AVL tree
*/
void dispose(node* t)
{
    if( t != NULL )
    {
        dispose( t->left );
        dispose( t->right );
        free(t);
    }
}

/*
    find a specific node's key in the tree
*/
node* find(int e, node* t )
{
    if( t == NULL )
        return NULL;
    if( e < t->data )
        return find( e, t->left );
    else if( e > t->data )
        return find( e, t->right );
    else
        return t;
}

/*
    find minimum node's key
*/
node* find_min( node* t )
{
    if( t == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else if( t->left == NULL )
        return t;
    else
        return find_min( t->left );
}

/*
    find maximum node's key
*/
node* find_max( node* t )
{
    if( t != NULL )
        while( t->right != NULL )
            t = t->right;

    return t;
}

/*
    get the height of a node
*/
int height( node* n )
{
    if( n == NULL )
        return -1;
    else
        return n->height;
}

/*
    get maximum value of two integers
*/
int max( int l, int r)
{
    return l > r ? l: r;
}

/*
    perform a rotation between a k2 node and its left child

    note: call single_rotate_with_left only if k2 node has a left child
*/

node* single_rotate_with_left( node* k2 )
{
    node* k1 = NULL;

    k1 = k2->left;
    k2->left = k1->right;
    k1->right = k2;

    k2->height = max( height( k2->left ), height( k2->right ) ) + 1;
    k1->height = max( height( k1->left ), k2->height ) + 1;
    return k1; /* new root */
}

/*
    perform a rotation between a node (k1) and its right child

    note: call single_rotate_with_right only if
    the k1 node has a right child
*/

node* single_rotate_with_right( node* k1 )
{
    node* k2;

    k2 = k1->right;
    k1->right = k2->left;
    k2->left = k1;

    k1->height = max( height( k1->left ), height( k1->right ) ) + 1;
    k2->height = max( height( k2->right ), k1->height ) + 1;

    return k2;  /* New root */
}

/*

    perform the left-right double rotation,

    note: call double_rotate_with_left only if k3 node has
    a left child and k3's left child has a right child
*/

node* double_rotate_with_left( node* k3 )
{
    /* Rotate between k1 and k2 */
    k3->left = single_rotate_with_right( k3->left );

    /* Rotate between K3 and k2 */
    return single_rotate_with_left( k3 );
}

/*
    perform the right-left double rotation

   notes: call double_rotate_with_right only if k1 has a
   right child and k1's right child has a left child
*/



node* double_rotate_with_right( node* k1 )
{
    /* rotate between K3 and k2 */
    k1->right = single_rotate_with_left( k1->right );

    /* rotate between k1 and k2 */
    return single_rotate_with_right( k1 );
}

/*
    insert a new node into the tree
*/
node* insert(int e, node* t )
{
    if( t == NULL )
    {
        /* Create and return a one-node tree */
        t = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if( t == NULL )
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Out of memory!!! (insert)\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            t->data = e;
            t->height = 0;
            t->left = t->right = NULL;
        }
    }
    else if( e < t->data )
    {
        t->left = insert( e, t->left );
        if( height( t->left ) - height( t->right ) == 2 ){
            if( e < t->left->data ){
                t = single_rotate_with_left( t );
            }
            else{
                t = double_rotate_with_left( t );
            }
        }
    }
    else if( e > t->data )
    {
        t->right = insert( e, t->right );
        if( height( t->right ) - height( t->left ) == 2 ){
            if( e > t->right->data ){
                t = single_rotate_with_right( t );
            }
            else{
                t = double_rotate_with_right( t );
            }
        }
    }
    /* Else X is in the tree already; we'll do nothing */

    t->height = max( height( t->left ), height( t->right ) ) + 1;
    return t;
}

/*
    remove a node in the tree
*/
node* delete( int e, node* t ){
    printf( "Sorry Delete is unimplemented %d remains\n", e );
    return t;
}

/*
    data data of a node
*/
int get(node* n)
{
    return n->data;
}

/*
    Recursively display AVL tree or subtree
*/
void display_avl(node* t)
{
    if (t == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%d",t->data);

    if(t->left != NULL)
        printf("(L:%d)",t->left->data);
    if(t->right != NULL)
        printf("(R:%d)",t->right->data);
    printf("\n");

    display_avl(t->left);
    display_avl(t->right);
}
```

avltree.h:

```
#ifndef AVLTREE_H
#define AVLTREE_H

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int height;
};



void dispose(node* t);
node* find(int e, node* t );
node* find_min( node* t );
node* find_max( node* t );
int height( node* n );
int max( int l, int r);
node* single_rotate_with_left( node* k2 );
node* single_rotate_with_right( node* k1 );
node* double_rotate_with_left( node* k3 );
node* double_rotate_with_right( node* k1 );
node* insert(int e, node* t );
node* delete( int e, node* t );
void display_avl(node* t);
int get(node* n);


#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif




#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

I've checked the syntax and have not seen anything out of the ordinary ... could someone help me a bit to make it work?

Thank you all.

Comment: Is delete a ( C++? ) reserved word? Your compiler seems to think so, maybe even in "C" mode. Perhaps use another name.

Comment: @CharlieBurns I had not considered that possibility, I'll do some tests and update.

Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Solved, thankyou Charlie Burns!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are compiling with code with a C++ compiler *, you get this error because [`delete` is a reserved word in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). Rename the function to `delete_avl` to avoid this problem.

---

* The `extern "C" ...` construct suggests that you at least plan to use this code in a C++ environment. If you do, you should move function prototypes inside the `extern "C"` block.